# Making object eligible to be cleaned up

Tags: java

I have very simple question but the answer is still not clear. If i have class Person and inside class Person there is one attribute which references to other object(ex: Account). If Person object is eligible for GC so either that attribute will be eligible to be cleaned up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as soon as the instance of Person is removed by the GC, the instance of Account will also get eligible if no other reference to it exists.

Answer (score 2):

> ***If Person object is eligible for GC so either that attribute will be eligible to be cleaned up?***

Yes, unless some other object has a reference to that very account object.

Basically any object that can't be referred to in the future is eligible for GC.

Comment: Hi! so if other objects hold reference to same object that attribute refers to. What will happen? Is Person object still cleaned up?

Comment: Yes. The person object will be cleaned up (garbage collected) while nothing will happen to the account object.

Comment: Yes, but the attribute object not

Comment: Thank you! I got it very helpful. Have nice day